# Is this the wrong way to handle AggregateException with Tasks

Tags: c#, exception

Need to handle AggregateExceptions gracefully. Is this way correct?

```
try
{
    var message = await _queue.ReceiveAsync();
    // rest of code
    //
    var response = await process(body);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
    {
         Trace.TraceError(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @erikkallen pointed out, you *shouldn't* be getting `AggregateException`s if you're using `await`.

But, if you weren't, you'd be handling them wrong.

An aggregate exception can actually be a *tree* of exceptions (i.e., it can contain other `AggregateExceptions`, which in turn contain more exceptions, etc). For that reason, you should use `Flatten`:

```
foreach (var e in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
```

See [Attached Child Tasks and Nested AggregateExceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

`await` unwraps `AggregateException`s, so there is no need to do what you're doing. However, if you had done `var response = process(body).Result`, then your handling would have been necessary.